# Adding vectors together

Tags: vectors

Hello i'm having trouble adding vectors together:

Question: (4i + 5j) and (6i + 8j)

Could you leave how you did it as well? thanks!

Comment: $i$ and $j$ are not quarternions here @DietrichBurde but placeholders for unit vectors.

Comment: $(4+6)\vec{i}+(5+8)\vec{j}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addition of vectors is defined componentwise/elementwise. Add like components together and you get what you need. In general,

$$(a_1 \mathbf{i} + b_1 \mathbf{j}) + (a_2 \mathbf{i} + b_2 \mathbf{j}) = (a_1 + a_2)\mathbf{i} + (b_1 + b_2)\mathbf{j}$$

Take it from here.

As this is your first post to this site, please note that it is expected you show what you have tried or your own thoughts of the question.